# Destruir sessão ativa após fechar o navegador

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho um sistema do qual preciso que a sessão esteja ativa devido a uma ferramenta interna, porém alguns usuários estão saindo do sistema fechando diretamente o navegador, sem clicar no botão **Sair** do sistema, onde é encerrado a sessão. Existe algum meio da sessão ser encerrada caso o usuário feche o sistema diretamente pelo navegador?

A sessão é criada após o usuário se logar:

```
$_SESSION["Logado"] = true;
```

E quando se clica no botão sair, destruo a sessão:

```
session_destroy();
```

Até aqui tudo certo, mas se o usuário fechar o navegador? Meu raciocínio inicial era criar uma sessão de tempo ao se logar:

```
$_SESSION["TempoAtivo"] = time() + 360;
```

Mas não sei o que fazer a partir daqui. Aceito sugestões em jquery, javascript e PHP.

Comment: Uma solução é utilizar cookies, dessa forma é possível colocar tempo de validade do Cookie

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesta resposta do SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24402832/4734177

Comment: Não testei, mas talvez funcione se vc fizer um Ajax chamando um .php que destrói a sessão após o fechamento da página com a função `$(window).unload(function() { ajax });`.

Comment: Pode fazer como o amigo acima relatou para destroir quando fechar o navegador. Maaas se o navegador travar ou forçar o fechamento dele inesperadamente a função não executa. Depois que passei a usar cookies nunca mais quis saber de `$_SESSION` para login. Somente uso cookies, guardo no banco a chave que está no cookies com o tempo de expiração tanto no banco quanto no navegador. E renovo o tempo da chave toda vez que o usuário muda de pagina.

Comment: Da uma olhada nisso depois. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a API [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) introduzida no HTML5, ela limpa a sessão localmente assim que o browser é fechado.
Para integrar com o PHP você poderia utilizar o seguinte exemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function submitform() {
    document.getElementById("hdnLogado").value = sessionStorage.getItem('logado');
    document.myform.submit();
} </script>
```

E no lado servidor:

```
$_REQUEST['logado'];
```